# Creating a type-level structure that contains a TypeLit with singletons

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation, singleton-type

Suppose I define some type-level structures like so:

```
import Data.Singletons.Prelude
import Data.Singletons.TH

singletons [d|
            data Natural = Succ Natural | Zero deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)
            data Coord = Coord Natural Natural deriving (Show, Eq)
           |]
```

However, instead of defining my own `Natural` type, I'd like to use `GHC.TypeLit.Nat` instead (if for no other reason than that the compiler error messages are nicer). The `singletons` package has already defined instances for the relevant classes in `Data.Singletons.TypeLits`, so this should be possible.

However, attempting to replace `Natural` with `Nat` like so

```
import Data.Singletons.Prelude
import Data.Singletons.TH
import Data.Singletons.TypeLits

singletons [d| data Coord = Coord Nat Nat deriving (Show, Eq) |]
```

yields the following error

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘GHC.Natural.Natural’ with ‘Nat’
      Expected type: Nat
        Actual type: Demote Nat
    • In the first argument of ‘Coord’, namely ‘(fromSing b_awjJ)’
      In the expression: (Coord (fromSing b_awjJ)) (fromSing b_awjK)
      In an equation for ‘fromSing’:
          fromSing (SCoord b_awjJ b_awjK)
            = (Coord (fromSing b_awjJ)) (fromSing b_awjK)
```

I understand why this error is appearing, but I am unsure how to proceed from here. Is it possible to create type-level structures that contain `TypeLits` using the `singletons` Template Haskell? And if not, is there some way to do this without having to implement all of the necessary singleton's machinery for `Coord` by hand?